# DSolve gives the wrong solution for an inhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I have the following inhomogeneous differential equation (sorry, I cannot come up with a simpler example)

```
Hom = -(-1 + 
     z) z^4 (8 (-5 + 6 z) f0[z] + (20 - 70 z + 52 z^2) f0'[
      z] + (-1 + z) z (2 (-5 + 7 z) f0''[z] + (-1 + z) z f0'''[z]))
InHom = -((24 z (24 + z (-48 + z (23 + 2 z))))/(-1 + z)) + (
  48 Log[1 - z] (z (18 + z (-24 + 5 z)) + 3 (-2 + z) (-1 + z) Log[1 - z]))/z
myeq = Hom + InHom
```

DSolve gives me a solution but it doesn't work, meaning that

```
DSolve[myeq == 0, f0[z], z][[1, 1, 2]];
myeq /. f0 -> ((% /. z -> #) &) // FullSimplify
% === 0
```

gives False. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Could be a bug... but the issue unfortunately seems to depend sensitively on the form of the rather complicated equation you are solving.

Comment: @Bill, the range of $z$ i'm interested is $0<z<1$, I tried to use `Assuming` but it doesn't change. The solution I'm interested in should be $0$ at $z=0$ and for small $z$ behave linearly in $z$.

Comment: Yeah, it says that the solution diverges as $z^{-5}$ but I don't trust that. For example, I can easily solve the differential equation as a power series.
For example
    `Nmax = 15; powser = ((1/z^3 myeq) /. 
   f0 -> ((Sum[\[Alpha][n] #^n, {n, 1, Nmax}]) &)); li = 
 CoefficientList[Series[powser, {z, 0, Nmax}], z] // Normal; lis = 
 Solve[li == 0 li]; fsol = (Sum[\[Alpha][n] z^n, {n, 1, Nmax}]) /. 
  lis[[1]]; Series[myeq /. f0 -> (fsol /. z -> # &), {z, 0, Nmax}]`
gives the first `Nmax` terms of the solution I'm interested in. It does not diverge at $z=0$

Comment: Your checking is wrong. Guess what `aaaa === 0` will evaluate to?

Comment: In fact, a simpler example is `Hom + InHom[[2]]`.

Comment: @xzczd I'm just saying that what should be zero isn't zero. If you just consider the homogeneous equation for example `a1 = DSolve[Hom == 0, f0[z], z][[1, 1, 2]];
FullSimplify[Hom /. f0 -> ((a1 /. z -> #) &)] === 0` gives you `True`

Comment: @bnado  Do you plan to report this error to Wolfram, Inc.?  If not, I may do so.

Comment: I know, but my point is you cannot verify in this way. A more obvious example: `1 - (-1)^(1/3) + (-1)^(2/3) === 0`. You may argue that you've already used `FullSimplify` in the previous step, then here's another counter example: `zero = FullSimplify[
   PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)] - 1/3 (\[Pi]^2 - 6 \[Pi] x + 6 x^2), 
   0 < x < Pi];
zero === 0`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I have reported it now

Comment: @xzczd ok, you are right that in general it's not a good way to check solutions. I also computed the result numerically for some values of $z$ to see that it was not zero but didn't include it here because it didn't look important. But you have a point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DSolve gives incorrect answer**

With `Hom`, `InHom`, and `myeq` as defined in the question, `DSolve` indeed gives an incorrect answer,

```
sol = DSolveValue[myeq == 0, f0, z];
FullSimplify[(myeq == 0) /. f0 -> %]
(* ((-1 + z) (z^2 - 5 (-2 + z) z Log[1 - z] + (14 + z (-14 + 3 z)) Log[1 - z]^2))/z == 0 *)
```

which is not, in general, `True`, as can be seen by evaluating the expression for a few values of `z`.  Note that none of the constants of integration appear in this expression, indicating that the error is not associated with the homogeneous equation.  This also can be demonstrated by solving the homogeneous equation directly.

```
DSolveValue[Hom == 0, f0, z]
FullSimplify[(Hom == 0) /. f0 -> %]
(* Function[{z}, C[1]/z^4 - (C[2] Log[1 - z])/z^4 + 
   (C[3] (1/(1 - z) - z - 1/4 (-1 - 2 Log[-1 + z])^2))/z^4] *)
(* True *)
```

**Obtaining correct answer**

Somewhat surprisingly (to me, at least), the correct answer can be obtained as follows.  Restructure `InHom` as

```
InHomsim = Collect[InHom, _Log, Simplify]
(* -((24 z (24 + z (-48 + z (23 + 2 z))))/(-1 + z)) + 
   48 (18 + z (-24 + 5 z)) Log[1 - z] + (144 (-2 + z) (-1 + z) Log[1 - z]^2)/z *)
```

Next, solve

```
sol1 = DSolveValue[Hom + InHomsim[[1]] == 0, f0, z];
FullSimplify[(Hom + InHomsim[[1]] == 0) /. f0 -> %]
(* True *)
sol2 = DSolveValue[Hom + InHomsim[[2]] == 0, f0, z];
FullSimplify[(Hom + InHomsim[[2]] == 0) /. f0 -> %]
(* True *)
sol3 = DSolveValue[Hom + InHomsim[[3]] == 0, f0, z];
FullSimplify[(Hom + InHomsim[[3]] == 0) /. f0 -> %]
(* True *)
```

Thus, correct solutions for each of the three additive components of `InHomsim` can be obtained without difficulty.  Simply add them to obtain the correct answer to the original equation.

```
Collect[(sol1[[2]] + sol2[[2]] + sol3[[2]]) /. C[i_] -> C[i]/3, C[_], FullSimplify];
soltr = Function[{z}, Evaluate@%]
FullSimplify[(myeq == 0) /. f0 -> soltr]
(* Function[{z}, C[1]/z^4 - (C[2] Log[1 - z])/z^4 + 
   (C[3] (1/(1 - z) - z - 1/4 (1 + 2 Log[-1 + z])^2))/z^4 + 
   (1/((-1 + z) z^4)) 4 (-6 (7 + 6 \[Pi]^2 (-1 + z) - z (7 + 4 z)) - 
   2 (-1 + z) Log[1 - z]^3 - 6 Log[1 - z] (-16 + z (15 + 2 z) + 
   (-1 + z) (-23 + Log[-1 + z]) Log[-1 + z]) + (-1 + z) Log[-1 + z] 
   (12 + Log[-1 + z] (-69 + 4 Log[-1 + z])) - 6 (-1 + z) Log[1 - z]^2 (5 + Log[z]) + 
   12 (-1 + z) Log[1 - z] PolyLog[2, z] - 12 (-1 + z) PolyLog[3, 1 - z])] *)
(* True *)
```

Evidently, `DSolve` can handle each of the three components of `InHomsim` but not the whole expression at once.

**Why the error?**

`DSolve` also can solve the general equation, `Hom + g[z] == 0`, correctly.

```
solgen = DSolveValue[Hom + g[z] == 0, f0, z];
FullSimplify[(Hom + g[z] == 0) /. f0 -> %]
(* True *)
```

Not surprisingly `solgen` contains three integrals over `g[z]` , two of them fairly complicated.  Because the `g[z]` in the question (namely `InHom`) and (as it happens) the kernels of the integrals both contain expressions with branch cuts, `DSolve` needs to select the proper contours along which to perform the integrals.  Probably, `DSolve` chose incorrect contours.

Comment: thanks, it does work now. I thought that `Assuming` would take care of the branch cuts but it's not the case. Only one thing, you have a `sol1` written instead of a `sol3` in your answer. Thanks again!